# How to make a ip point to other ip and port (from two apache virtual hosts) on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache

I need to have different IP addresses pointing to an specific ip address and port on a EC2 instance, where i have running multiple sites on Apache virtual hosts
For example:
xx.xx.xx.xx -> 107.22.56.213:8080
yy.yy.yy.yy -> 107.22.56.213:8081

Is this posible on AWS?

EDIT 1:

Ok I have attached two different IP addresses to a single instance. But I am having problems configuring the reverse proxy, my 000-default.conf it is like this:

```
<VirtualHost 54.158.187.139:80>
  ProxyPass / 127.0.0.1:8080
  ProxyPassReverse / 127.0.0.1:8080
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 35.153.37.243:80>
  ProxyPass / 127.0.0.1:8081
  ProxyPassReverse / 127.0.0.1:8081
</VirtualHost>
```

But it is still showing the default 000-default site, and I have already restarted the apache2 service

Comment: hm ... I would try to add `ServerName` in the `VirtualHost` if it doesn't show the right site.

Comment: Like this? 


<VirtualHost 54.158.187.139:80>
        ServerName 54.158.187.139
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 35.153.37.243:80>
        ServerName 35.153.37.243
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8081/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8081/
</VirtualHost>

Comment: I *think* the ServerName should be the domain to request at the source server,  ProxyPreserveHost might not be OK here, depending on config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can attach multiple elastic network interfaces on your ec2 server and attach each ENI with elastic IP, you can configure your aoache virtual to listen to specific IP and specific port:

This is a very useful blog

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/multiple-ip-addresses-for-ec2-instances-in-a-virtual-private-cloud/ 
https://vannstudios.com/how-to-set-up-multiple-elastic-ip-for-amazon-ec2-instance

for Proxy the URL below has a similar case to you:

https://serverfault.com/questions/557478/apache-reverse-proxy-forwarding-different-source-ip-ranges-to-different-destinat

```
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 54.158.187.139
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://127.0.0.1:8080/$1 [P]
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080 

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} 35.153.37.243
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://127.0.0.1:8081/$1 [P]
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8081/
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have successfuy attached two different ip addresses on the same instance. But I am having trouble configuring apache reverse proxy. Please see edited question.

Comment: I edited the answer , please vote to the answer and mark it verified once you confirm

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not 100% what you asked, but it's easy to put a NGINX server in front of Apache one, and it performs better most of the time.
Nginx config (with caching) is as simple as ...

```
http{

    proxy_cache_path /my_nginx_cache_folder levels=1:2 keys_zone=my_nginx_cache:2g max_size=2g
                     inactive=30d use_temp_path=off;


    server {

        listen       443 ssl;
        server_name  www.mydomain.com;

        ssl_certificate         /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key     /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.mydomain.com/privkey.pem; 

        location / {

                proxy_pass  http://mydomain-on-anotherip.com:8081;

                # the domain to request at the above IP
                proxy_set_header Host      mydomain.com;

                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

                # for this path, tell it to use the cache defined above
                proxy_cache             my_nginx_cache;

        } 
    } 
}
```

I did this with many of my servers and it works nicely, and at your source server, you can specify cache headers, so that the upper NGINX server will cache them for as long as you specify:

```php
<?php 
    $cache_seconds = 60*60*24;
    header("Expires: ".gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T', time()+$cache_seconds));
    header("Cache-Control:public, max-age=".$cache_seconds); 
?>
```

With a similar config, my stats show pages load in 0.250 seconds, from 0.800 seconds.

Comment: Thanks, If i can't do what I want with Apache I will use Nginx